# How can I include both RcppEigen.h and RcppArmadillo.h in the same cpp file (in R)?

Tags: eigen, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I am trying to load both by doing:

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>                           // do this AFTER including stan/math
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
```

However I get the error: "The file 'Rcpp.h' should not be included. Please correct to include only 'RcppArmadillo.h'."

How can I use both in the same file? I want to make some functions which make use of both packages

Comment: That's being done by other packages (and GitHub code search is great for this).  I think you just need to reorder as RcppArmadillo is picky about no Rcpp headers before it starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in my comment, you had the order wrong. RcppArmadillo errors when Rcpp.h was included before so it has to be first.

Here is a minimal working file, printing a matrix with each flavor.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void fooArma(const arma::mat& m) {
    m.print("arma: matrix m");
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void fooEigen(const Eigen::MatrixXd& m) {
    Rcpp::Rcout << "eigen\n" << m << std::endl;
}

/*** R
m <- matrix(1:9,3,3) * 1.0
fooArma(m)
fooEigen(m)
*/
```